# pgfplotstabel - create table with time column

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, filecontents

I try to create a table with a column for date and time from a file `data.txt`. I can create a diagram but when I type `\pgfplotstabletypeset` for a table following error occurs:

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Table 'data.txt' appears to have too many
>   columns in line 1:

I also tried adding the option `\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma]{data.txt}`. Then I get this error:

> ! Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '2015-09-13 21:00:00'
>   as a floating point number, sorry.

How can I fix this?
Thank you!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
date, value
2015-09-13 21:00:00, 922
2015-09-13 22:00:00, 3993
2015-09-13 23:00:00, 3003
2015-09-14 00:00:00, 991
2015-09-14 01:00:00, 2021
2015-09-14 02:00:00, 841
2015-09-14 03:00:00, 2812
2015-09-14 14:00:00, 991
2015-09-14 15:00:00, 231
2015-09-14 16:00:00, 678

\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/date/.style={date type={\day.\month.\year},
                                       column name=Datum},
    columns/date/.style={date type={\hour:\minute},
                                       column name=Zeit},
    columns/value/.style={column name=Value},
    ]{data.txt}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want get a table with 2 columns?

Comment: There are two problems: 1) you need `col sep=comma`, because that's how columns are seperated in `data.txt` and 2) `date type` does not support time, therefore `\hour` and `\minute` are not defined. The easy way out would be to change `data.txt` to 3 columns (date, time, value) and use `string type` for the time. If this can't be done, it is probably possible to write some macrs to handle the first column (but currently I don't have the time for this, sorry).

Comment: Thank you Mike. `string type` works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

First, you need to use `col sep=comma`, because that's how the columns are seperated in `data.txt`.

And second, `date type` does not support time. Therefore the commands `\hour` and `\minute` are not defined.

If you have controll over the format of `data.txt`, then the easy way out is to change it to three columns (`date, time, value`). If you then leave out the seconds, the `time` column already contains the format you want.

Then use the column type `string type` for the new column, which will print the contents as is (i.e. it will not be parsed as a number).

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
date, time, value
2015-09-13, 21:00, 922
2015-09-13, 22:00, 3993
2015-09-13, 23:00, 3003
2015-09-14, 00:00, 991
2015-09-14, 01:00, 2021
2015-09-14, 02:00, 841
2015-09-14, 03:00, 2812
2015-09-14, 14:00, 991
2015-09-14, 15:00, 231
2015-09-14, 16:00, 678

\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    columns/date/.style={date type={\day.\month.\year},
                                       column name=Datum},
    columns/time/.style={string type,
                                       column name=Zeit},
    columns/value/.style={column name=Value},
    ]{data.txt}

\end{document}
```

If you also want to plot the data, you can make four columns like this:

```
dt, date, time, value
2015-09-13 21:00, 2015-09-13, 21:00, 922
```

In this case, you have to add a list of columns to the table, so the first is ignored:

```
\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=comma,
    columns={date,time,value},
```